# AJAX request not passing the data on controller's $_POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have this ajax code. I am getting the values of my textboxes, the problem here is that the data in ajax call can't be posted in my controller.

```
setTimeout(function()
    {
        var random_pct = 25 + Math.round(Math.random() * 30);

       // The form data are subbmitted, we can forward the progress to 70%
        neonLogin.setPercentage(40 + random_pct);
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        // Send data to the server
        $.ajax({
            url: baseurl + 'index.php?login/ajax_login',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: { email: $("#email").val(),password: $("#password").val() },
            error: function(data, status, textError)
            {
                // alert('Error: ' + xhr.responseText + ' - ' + status + ' - ' + textError);
                console.log(data);
                console.log('Error: ' + data.responseText + ' - ' + status + ' - ' + textError);
            },
            success: function(response)
            {
                console.log($('#email').val());
                console.log($('#password').val());
                console.log(response);

                // alert(response.submitted_data);
                // Login status [success|invalid]
                var login_status = response.login_status;
                // alert(response.login_status);
                // Form is fully completed, we update the percentage
                neonLogin.setPercentage(100);


                // We will give some time for the animation to finish, then execute the following procedures    
                setTimeout(function()
                {
                    // If login is invalid, we store the 
                    if(login_status == 'invalid')
                    {
                        $(".login-page").removeClass('logging-in');
                                    neonLogin.resetProgressBar(true);
                    }
                    else
                        if(login_status == 'success')
                        {
                            // Redirect to login page
                            setTimeout(function()
                            {
                                var redirect_url = baseurl;

                                if(response.redirect_url && response.redirect_url.length)
                                {
                                    redirect_url = response.redirect_url;
                                }

                            window.location.href = redirect_url;
                            }, 400);
                        }

                    }, 1000);
                }
            });
        }, 650);
```

here is what my controller looks like.

```
function ajax_login()
{
    // $this->output->set_header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $response = array();

    //Recieving post input of email, password from ajax request
    $email      = $_POST["email"];
    $password   = $_POST["password"];
    $response['submitted_data'] = $_POST;

    // $response['email'] = $_POST['email'];
    // $response['password'] = $_POST['password'];

    //Validating login
    $login_status = $this->validate_login( $email ,  $password );
    $response['login_status'] = $login_status;
    if ($login_status == 'success') {
        $response['redirect_url'] = base_url().'index.php?admin/dashboard';
    }

    //Replying ajax request with validation response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

There is no problem in json_encode. But I am not getting the $_POST['email'] and $_POST['password'] that is passed on my ajax request. thank you for all the help.

Comment: 'baseurl' variable is undefined. please check the url is correct. If you use the chrome go to the console and check log xmlhttprequests and see if ajax is going, and if its going check whether it's the correct url

Comment: nope baseurl is not undefined sir.

Comment: Did you check the ajax url in console?

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller's function add a test line like this: `$response["test"] = "test";`.
Make sure that it will show up in your console.

Change your ajax url to: `index.php/login/ajax_login`

In CodeIgniter, it's better to use the `$this->input->post();` instead of `$_POST[]`. If you want xss protection (recommended) than this is how you need to declare that:

```
$email = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post("email"));
$password = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post("password"));
```

And finally, at the end of your Controller set the output type instead of `echo`:

```
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($response));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is what i did. 

$email = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post("email"));
  $password = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post("password"));
  $response['submitted_data'] = $_POST;

Comment: Does anything appears in your console?

Comment: yes sir. but the $response['submitted_data'] = $_POST still display null.

Comment: I have tried your code in my environment, and default I have 403 Forbidden error, but when I remove the `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` and define the correct url: `url: '<?= base_url("index.php/login/ajax_login"); ?>',` it works like a charm. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

You had your code like this:

```
var email = $("#email").val();
var password = $("#password").val();
```

`data: { email: $("#email").val(),password: $("#password").val() },`

that's why your input post for `email` and `password` in the controller was recognized.

**Change `data` property into this:**
`data: { 'email': $("#email").val(),'password': $("#password").val() },`

Let me know if it helped. Best Regards